# get related objects in django-tastypie using obj.modelname_set.all()

Tags: django, tastypie

I am trying to create an api using django tastypie. in my project I have two models Question and Answers. The Answers model has the foreign key to question model. In my api.py I have two resources QuestionResource and AnswerResource.

What i want to do is that when i retrieve a question instance using api call i want to retrieve the related answers instance also. I tried this using adding a key in bundle.data dict and implement it in alter_detail_data_to_serialize. bt what i get as response is a list of objects not the serialized json object. what I got is

and my Code is

```
 class QuestionResource(ModelResource):
    answer=fields.ToManyField('quiz.api.AnswerResource', 'answer', null=True, full=True)
    topic=fields.ForeignKey(TopicResource,'topic')
    difficulty=fields.ForeignKey(DifficultyLevelResource, 'difficulty')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Question.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'question'
        authorization = Authorization()
        serializer = PrettyJSONSerializer()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
        always_return_data = True
        filtering={'id':ALL,
                'answer':ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
    }

def alter_detail_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):

    data.data['answers']=[obj for obj in data.obj.answer_set.all()]
    return data

def dehydrate(self,bundle):
    bundle.data['related']=bundle.obj.answer_set.all()
    return bundle

class AnswerResource(ModelResource):
    question=fields.ToOneField('quiz.api.QuestionResource', 'answer', null=True,full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Answer.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'answer'
        authorization = Authorization()
        serializer = PrettyJSONSerializer()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
        always_return_data = True
        filtering={
                'question':ALL_WITH_RELATIONS

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple, as per the api documentation i had to pass an attirbute to the related field.

```
 class QuestionResource(ModelResource):
    answer=fields.ToManyField('quiz.api.AnswerResource', 'answer_set', null=True, full=True)

class AnswerResource(ModelResource):
    question=fields.ToOneField('quiz.api.QuestionResource', 'question', null=True)
```

read the docs  http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships

Answer (score 6):

You could add a property to your Question model to get the answer e.g.

```
def get_answer(self):
    ... return the correct answer
```

then in QuestionResource use:

```
answer = fields.CharField(attribute='get_answer', readonly=True)
```

Comment: Thanx for ur response, i tried with adding the same method on the resource, and what it returns is                                                   "related": "[<Answer: 10>, <Answer: 20>, <Answer: 15>, <Answer: 00>]" This is the simple string but i want to retrieve answers objects in a serialized form

Comment: Ah OK I thought you just wanted to be able to return and answer inline as string. If you want a subset in the api format it would be using ToManyField as you have in your paste, doe you have answers as a m2m on the model? if not i think  your would need answer_set as the second argument.

Comment: No, i dont have a m2m field in any model . I have a foreignkey to Question in answer model using which i can obtain related objects. I tried all the things bt unable to get serialized Answer objects

Comment: then it would probably need to be question=fields.ToOneField('quiz.api.QuestionResource', 'question', null=True,full=True) and answer=fields.ToManyField('quiz.api.AnswerResource', 'answer_set', null=True, full=True) in your two resources

Comment: JamesO, if u see my code i have already added these both fields in the models bt still it doesn't works....... now can anyone tell me any logoc or any other way which leads me to get the related objects

Comment: i'd had a look at your code, you are pointing both resources to 'answer' not answer_set and question as above?